# MySQL query to get data for Spacetree (jit)

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to extract data from MySQL tables and the convert to JSON format. All I need is to make a tree from the data as in Spacetree. The sample I'm using is:

http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html

I've searched in forums. I found somethin but not sure I'm right or wrong. See the following:
I created json.php as follows

```
<?php 
include_once("connect_to_mysql.php"); 
$query = "SELECT profile.name, profile.faculty, profile.course, subject.subject_id, subject.subject_name, grade.CGPA, grade.grades
          FROM profile
          LEFT JOIN subject on profile.stud_id = subject.stud_id
          LEFT JOIN grade on subject.subject_id = grade.subject_id"; 
$result=mysql_query($query);

$_ResultSet = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $_ResultSet[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($_ResultSet); 
?>
```

Then made changes in example1.js file as follows

```
//init data

$.getJSON("storescripts/json.php", function(data) {
    var add = 0;
    var json = {    
        id: "node1",
        name: "Students Names",
        data: {},
        $.each(data, function(i, j) {
            // use: j.columnName
            children: [{
                id: add+1,
                name: j.name,
                data: {},
                children: [{
                    id: add+1,
                    name: j.course,
                    data: {},
                    children: [{
                        id: add+1,
                        name: j.CGPA,
                        data: {},
                        children: [{
                            id: add+1,
                            name: j.grade,
                            data: {},
                            children: []
                        }]

                    }]
                }]
            }]
        },

              });
});
```

I don't know whether its correct or not. but here $.each(data, function(i, j) { it gives error.
I want the result as follows:

```
var json = {
    id: 1,
    name: "Students Records",
    data: {},
    children: [{
        id: 2,
        name: "Adam",
        data: {},
        children: [{
            id: 3,
            name: "Intro 2 Business",
            data: {},
            children: [{
                id: 4,
                name: "3.5",
                data: {},
                children: [{
                    id: 5,
                    name: "A+",
                    data: {},
                    children: []
                }]

            }]
        }, {
            id: 6,
            name: "Marketing Essential",
            data: {},
            children: [{
                id: 7,
                name: "3.23",
                data: {},
                children: [{
                    id: 8,
                    name: "A",
                    data: {},
                    children: []
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        id: 9,
        name: "Peter",
        data: {},
        children: [{
            id: 10,
            name: "Image Processing",
            data: {},
            children: [{
                id: 11,
                name: "3.27",
                data: {},
                children: [{
                    id: 12,
                    name: "A",
                    data: {},
                    children: []
                }, ]


            }]
        }, {
            id: 13,
            name: "Computer Vision",
            data: {},
            children: [{
                id: 14,
                name: "3.38",
                data: {},
                children: [{
                    id: 15,
                    name: "A",
                    data: {},
                    children: []
                }, ]
            }, ]
        }, {
            id: 16,
            name: "Neural Networks",
            data: {},
            children: [{
                id: 17,
                name: "3.59",
                data: {},
                children: [{
                    id: 18,
                    name: "A",
                    data: {},
                    children: []
                }, ]
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        id: 19,
        name: "Luke",
        data: {},
        children: [{
            id: 20,
            name: "Opinion Mining",
            data: {},
            children: [{
                id: 21,
                name: "3.67",
                data: {},
                children: [{
                    id: 22,
                    name: "A",
                    data: {},
                    children: []
                }, ]

            }]
        }, {
            id: 23,
            name: "Macine Learning",
            data: {},
            children: [{
                id: 24,
                name: "3.84",
                data: {},
                children: [{
                    id: 25,
                    name: "A",
                    data: {},
                    children: []
                }]

            }]
        }, {
            id: 26,
            name: "Semantic Web",
            data: {},
            children: [{
                id: 27,
                name: "3.105",
                data: {},
                children: [{
                    id: 28,
                    name: "A",
                    data: {},
                    children: []
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            id: 29,
            name: "NLP",
            data: {},
            children: [{
                id: 30,
                name: "3.110",
                data: {},
                children: [{
                    id: 31,
                    name: "A",
                    data: {},
                    children: []
                }]

            }]

        }]
    }, {
        id: 32,
        name: "Christopher",
        data: {},
        children: [{
            id: 33,
            name: "Poetry course",
            data: {},
            children: [{
                id: 34,
                name: "3.132",
                data: {},
                children: [{
                    id: 35,
                    name: "A",
                    data: {},
                    children: []
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            id: 36,
            name: "Linguistics course",
            data: {},
            children: [{
                id: 37,
                name: "3.139",
                data: {},
                children: [{
                    id: 38,
                    name: "A",
                    data: {},
                    children: []
                }]

            }]
        }]
    }]
};
```

It should be dynamically changing as I change the data in the database tables.

### Any help will be appreciated.

I did like following, but not displaying anything. When make a separate php page the it works and display results in JSON form. But in .js it's not working.

```
function init(){

    //init data

    //include .js file inside .js file
    /*document.writeln("<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery/jquery.min.js'></script>");*/

    /*var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = 'jquery/jquery.min.js';
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);*/

    var imported = document.createElement('script');
    imported.src = 'jquery/jquery.min.js';
    document.head.appendChild(imported);

    $.getJSON("storescripts/json.php", function(data) {

        document.writeln("var json = {");   
        document.writeln('id: "node1",');
        document.writeln('name: "Students Names",');
        document.writeln("data: {},");
        $.each(data, function(i, j) {
            // use: j.columnName

            for(var add = 0; add <= i; add++){
                document.writeln("children: [{");
                document.writeln("id:" + (++add) + ",");
                document.writeln("name:" + j.name + ",");
                document.writeln("data: {},");
                document.writeln("children: [{");
                document.writeln("id:" + (++add) + ",");
                document.writeln("name:" + j.course + ",");
                document.writeln("data: {},");
                document.writeln("children: [{");
                document.writeln("id:" + (++add) + ",");
                document.writeln("name:" + j.CGPA + ",");
                document.writeln("data: {},");
                document.writeln("children: [{");
                document.writeln("id:" + (++add) + ",");
                document.writeln("name:" + j.grade + ",");
                document.writeln("data: {},");
                document.writeln("children: []");
                document.writeln("}]");
                document.writeln("}]");
                document.writeln("}]");
                document.writeln("}]");
            }
        });
        document.writeln("};");
    });
}
```

If please can help me. And tell me whether I included the jquery.min.js file correctly?? And is the for loop is correct logically or not? Or technically while or do while loop will be better?

Thanks

Comment: Your parentheses and braces don't match properly in the `init()` function.

Comment: Where is `id: "node"+i` in your desired output?

Comment: Only parenthesis is the problem???

Comment: can i just add 1, 2, 3,... to the ids???

Comment: `i` is the index of each element in the array, `j` is the value.

Comment: `i` will go 0, 1, 2, 3, ... as it iterates through `data`.

Comment: I don't understand your desired data structure. What determines whether a row should be a child or the next element of the array?

Comment: I edited the init. May be now it's more clear to you. I've used var add to give unique value to the id of each node. I wanted to post screen shots but can't post as I'm not allowed. The parent node is "Students Names". In each row the name is child of the parent "Students Names". Each person will have more than one courses, these courses are its children. Each course has its child CGPA, and grade is child of CGPA.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON("storescripts/json.php", function(data) {
    var json = rows_to_tree(data);
    // Do stuff with json
});

function rows_to_tree(rows) {
    var id = 1;
    var result = { id: id++, name: "Student Records", data: {}, children: {} };
    var tree = result.children;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = rows[i];
        var student = row.name, course = row.course, cgpa = row.CGPA, grades = row.grades;
        // First create all the children as objects, to make searching easier
        tree[student] = tree[student] || { id: id++, name: student, data: {}, children: {} };
        tree[student].children[course] = tree[student].children[course] || { id: id++, name: course, data: {}, children: {} };
        tree[student].children[course].children[cgpa] = tree[student].children[course].children[cgpa] || { id: id++, name: cgpa, data: {}, children: {} };
        tree[student].children[course].children[cgpa].children[grades] = tree[student].children[course].children[cgpa].children[grades] || { id: id++, name: grades, data: {}, children: [] };
    }
    // Now convert the children objects to arrays
    result.children = obj_to_array(result.children);
    $.each(result.children, function(k, value) {
        value.children = obj_to_array(value.children);
        $.each(value.children, function(k, value2) {
            value2.children = obj_to_array(value2.children);
            $.each(value2.children, function(k, value3) {
                value3.children = obj_to_array(value3.children);
            });
        });
    });
    return result;
}

function obj_to_array(obj) {
    return $.map(obj, function(value) {
        return [value];
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it's complicated to understand actually, but I edit and add something to my question. If you can check and reply again. i did something, when I want to display in a separate php page it works but here in .js file not working.

Comment: You never wrote a `<script>` line in your JS. But using `document.write()` is a horrible way to build data structures. Why don't you just use the function I gave?

Comment: I can't understand that. Here $.getJSON("storescripts/json.php", function(data) {
    var tree = rows_to_tree(data);
    // Do stuff with tree
}); Here you have added comment // Do stuff with tree. Don't know what to do here??? So Sorry to disturb you again and again. But anyway thanks for replying me.

Comment: I'm just showing you how to build the data structure you want. I don't know what you're planning to use it for, so I just put a comment there. `tree` is the variable that contains the result you wanted, like `json` in your question.

Comment: I'm using exactly this app(http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html). Now in this app there is example1.js, in which there's a json array, from which the app reads data, and display in the form of treeview. I want to bring data from my MySQL database, and make it available in the example1.js in the exact json format.  So that I replace the json with my own data, and display my data on the page in tree form as in the app. if you can please check the app that I've given you the link then you will understand at once. thanks a lot. Hopefully you'll not mind..

Comment: I'm not going to read your application. You said "I want a result like XXX", and that's what my function returns. So if that's what you want, my function should work for you.

Comment: yup sure thanks. But I can't make the json array from it like I've given above (var json={......}). Anyway I'm still trying to understand your function and get what I want. Thanks

Comment: I've changed the beginning of the answer, does that make it clearer? You don't need to use all that `document.writeln` stuff to assign a Javascript variable, you just assign it in the Javascript and then use the variable. If you don't understand this, you need to learn Javascript better, and I'm not going to try to teach you that.